# jQuery UI Dialog always opening behind Fancybox windows

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, dialog, fancybox

I'm trying to open jQuery dialog *within* AJAX loaded Fancybox window.

In Fancybox content I have following script:

```
$('#firma_picker').load( $('#firma_opener').attr('href') );
$('#firma_picker').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Výber firmy',
                width: 300,
                height: 400,
                modal: false,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false
            });



$('#firma_opener').click(function() {
            $('#firma_picker').dialog('open');
            $('#firma_picker').dialog('moveToTop');

            return false;
});
```

Unfortunately, Dialog is *ALWAYS* opened behind the Fancybox window. I try changing the `z-index` settings to `.ui-dialog` selector, but no luck. I did the same to 'firma_picker' DIV.

It seems to me, that Dialog DIV code is always appended to body. So I have tried appendTo directive tio append content to element within Fancybox, but this doesn't work at all and Dilog is always appended to body.

Code is applied to this HTML:

```
<div>
        <label>Firma:</label><input type="text" name="nadpis" style="width: 325px; height: 14px;" placeholder="Kliknite na ikonu vyhľadávania vpravo" />
        <a id="firma_opener" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl; ?>/admin/reklama/firmasearch"><img src="" alt="ikona vyhľadávania" /></a> <-- tu je ikona
        <div id="firma_picker"></div>
</div>
```

I spent few hours recently to get this resolved, but I haven't any more clues. Any ideas ? thank you.
Ivan

PS: datepicker is running OK within Fancybox window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fancybox containers have these `z-index` values :

```
.fancybox-overlay {
  z-index : 8010;
}

.fancybox-opened {
  z-index : 8030;
}
```

The default `z-index` for a UI Dialog (`.ui-dialog`) is `1002`

Try setting a higher `z-index` than fancybox selectors to your UI Dialog selector(s), something like :

```
.ui-dialog {
  z-index : 9020 !important;
}
```

... **notice** that `!important` is important ;)

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g4sZV/)**

Comment: I think I did all these tries already. But finally it's working on the Fiddle, so it's must working. Let me do more training with my js / css and I'll let you know. Thanks !

Comment: Finally, this was my trivial mistake :) I have simply edited css on wrong level. This Z-index stuff did the job, many thanks !